# Performance issues after migrating from Spring Boot 1 to Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, performance, spring-boot, migration

I recently migrated a pretty big application from Spring Boot 1 to Spring Boot 2. Everything builds just fine, but i soon realized, that the build time is twice as high compared to the version before (from ~10 to 15 minutes to ~25-35 minutes).

During the tests, the application context gets restarted around 15 times with the annotation `@DirtiesContext`. I'm not really happy with that usage, but currently this cannot be resolved differently. I can say for certain, that starting the application context takes way longer in Spring Boot 2 than in Spring Boot 1.

Does anyone have similar problems? How should i start analyzing this? Any ideas what the reason could be? Could it be based on a default behaviour that differentiates between the two versions of Spring Boot?

Comment: Figure out what is taking longer... We had issues with memory leading to aggressive GC behavior slowing things down considerably.

Comment: In our (the Spring Boot team's experience), Spring Boot itself should start faster in version 2 than it did in version 1. That may not be the case for a dependency that you're using that has changed version. I agree with Marco and Marten that you need to identify what's taking longer. A profiler is a good way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In that situation, I think the best approach is to use a profiler, like VisualVM. 
Even locally you can find out what is happening. 
Actually, profiling is always a good idea after any version change.

Comment: Okey, thanks for these ideas, I'll try and update you as soon as i know more